# Найти число для возведения и степень степенного числа или их отсутствие

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, математика, факторизация

Я немного запуталась. В мою функцию поступает в качестве аргумента число. Нужно определить, является ли это число степенным. То есть если пришло число 4, то нужно вывести число, которое нужно возвести в степень и саму степень. В данному случае это будут 2 и 2.

```js
let exponentialNumber = function (n) {
        let divisors = [];
        let number = n;
        let count = 1;
        for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i === 0) divisors.push(i);
        }
        divisors.forEach(function (item) {
            number = n;
            while (number % item === 0 && number >= 1) {
                count++;
                number = number / item;
                console.log(item);
            }
        });
    };

    exponentialNumber(4);
    exponentialNumber(81);
```

Comment: явно есть еще ограничения, например эти числа должны быть целыми? или степень не должна быть равна 1?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ именно, забыла об этом написать

Comment: а что делать в случае с 16? это 2 в 4 и 4 в 2

Comment: @ThisMan можно вывести один из них любой

Comment: Начните с факторизации (разложение числа на простые множители) и смотрите их степени. Если это простое число в степени - решение найдено. Если простых множителей несколько - ищите НОД их степеней. Если 1 - это не степень; если больше 1 - значит, степень...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начните с простого:

```js
let exponentialNumber = function(n) {
  let stop = Math.sqrt(n);
  for (let i = 2; i <= stop; i++) {
    let cur = n;
    let count = 0;
    while (cur > 1 && cur % i == 0) {
      count++;
      cur = cur / i;
    }
    if (cur == 1) {
      console.log(n, "=", i, "^", count);
      return;
    }
  }
  console.log(n, "NO");
};

exponentialNumber(4);
exponentialNumber(81);
exponentialNumber(29791);
exponentialNumber(10000);
exponentialNumber(10001);
```

Answer (score 0):

Факторизация числа за O(sqrt(n)/2).

```
let max = (a, b) => {
    if (a > b) return a;
  else return b;
}
let factorize = (a) => {
    let max_factor = 0, ans = 1, aa = a;
  while (a % 2 == 0) max_factor++, a /= 2, ans = 2;
  let i = 3;
  while (i * i <= a)
  {
    let curr = 0;
    while(a % i == 0) curr ++, a /= i;
    if (max(max_factor, curr) != max_factor && max_factor > 0)
        return [aa, 1]
    if (curr > 0) ans *= i;
    if (curr > 0 && max_factor == 0) max_factor = curr;

    i += 2;
  }
  ans *= a;
  if (a > 1 && max_factor > 1) return [aa, 1];
  if (max_factor == 0) max_factor = 1;
  return [ans, max_factor];
}
console.log(factorize(123));
console.log(factorize(8));

console.log(factorize(225));

console.log(factorize(62748517));
```